# Android onResume called when screen turns off

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, android-anr-dialog

First of all, I don't speak English, so please forgive me for my terrible grammar.

I try to create Android game, using `GLSurfaceView`.
I read ["Beginning of Android Game"](http://beginning-android-games.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ch09-jumper/src/) (*the link is sample code*) in Japanese and imitate its code, so my game almost works fine.
But I have a problem.
When android turns off the screen, onPause of the activity is called as expected.
But sometimes (not always) onResume is called and then `onPause()` is called again, although the screen is still black.
In `onResume` I call `GLSurfaceView()`.resume, so `onSurfaceCreated()` and `onSurfaceChanged()` are also called.
After this, the game puts out ANR.

[Expected flow]
onPause - (turn on the screen) - onResume - onSurfaceCreated - onSurfaceChanged
[Problematic flow]
onPause - onResume - onPause - onSurfaceCreated - onSurfaceChanged - (turn on the screen) - ANR

Even in the problematic case, GLSurfaceView.onDrawFrame is called normally, and the game is being rendered.
But it doesn't accept any tap.Is there infinite loop?

I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297851/funky-android-activity-behavior-when-screen-turns-off?rq=1), for example.
But I think there is no configuration Change.
In Android `Manifest`,

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize`

was already declared.
And I can't move my code into Application class because I want to do something (e.g. reload some textures) in `onSurfaceCreated` method.

So my question is...

> Why is the onResume method called?
>
> <s>Why it causes ANR?</s>
> <s>And How can I avoid this ANR?</s>
> EDIT: the problem was solved.I appreciate it!

Here is my activity.

```
public abstract class GLGame extends Activity implements Game, Renderer {
    enum GLGameState {
        Initialized,
        Running,
        Paused,
        Finished,
        Idle
    }
    /////////////////////////////inter-ad
    private static class AdHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<GLGame> mActivity;
        AdHandler(GLGame activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<GLGame>(activity);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            GLGame activity = mActivity.get();
            switch(msg.what){
            case 0:
                if (activity != null) {
                    activity.showInterstitial();
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if (activity != null) {
                    activity.prepareInterstitial();
                }
                break;
            }

            return;
        }
    };
    Handler handler =new AdHandler(this);
    /////////////////////////////inter-ad    

    //ad
    static InterstitialAd interstitial;
    static AdRequest adRequest;
    AdView adView;
    //////////////////////////////// //ad

    GLSurfaceView glView;
    GLGraphics glGraphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    GLGameState state = GLGameState.Initialized;
    Object stateChanged = new Object();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        /////////////////////////////calculate and normalize the view size    
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

        float density = displaymetrics.densityDpi/160f;
        int adpix = (int)( 50*density);
        int navvarpix = (int)( 25*density);
        int heightSubAd = displaymetrics.heightPixels -navvarpix-adpix;

        int ratioWidth=10;
        int ratioHeight=16;
        boolean isWidthLong = displaymetrics.widthPixels/(float)heightSubAd > ratioWidth/(float)ratioHeight;
        int width = isWidthLong ? heightSubAd * ratioWidth / ratioHeight : displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = isWidthLong ? heightSubAd : displaymetrics.widthPixels * ratioHeight/ratioWidth;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
        lp.setMargins((displaymetrics.widthPixels-width)/2, 0, 0, (displaymetrics.widthPixels-width)/2);
        ///////////////////////////// //calc    

        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glView.setRenderer(this);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "MY_NUMBER");
        lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, adpix);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        adView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        layout.setId(0);
        layout.addView(glView);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        setContentView(layout);

        /////////////////////////////////request inter-ad
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "MY_NUMBER");
        adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.addTestDevice("MY_NUMBER");
        adRequest.addTestDevice("MY_NUMBER");
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        /////////////////////////////////inter-ad

        glGraphics = new GLGraphics(glView);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, glView, 1, 1);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        glGraphics.setGL(gl);

        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            if(state == GLGameState.Initialized)
                screen = getStartScreen();
            state = GLGameState.Running;
            screen.resume();
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        GLGameState state = null;

        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            state = this.state;
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Running) {
            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            screen.update(deltaTime);
            screen.present(deltaTime);
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Paused) {
            screen.pause();
            synchronized(stateChanged) {
                this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
                stateChanged.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Finished) {
            screen.pause();
            screen.dispose();
            synchronized(stateChanged) {
                this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
                stateChanged.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            if(isFinishing())
                state = GLGameState.Finished;
            else
                state = GLGameState.Paused;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    stateChanged.wait();
                    break;
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        glView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    public GLGraphics getGLGraphics() {
        return glGraphics;
    }

    @Override
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("We are using OpenGL!");
    }

    @Override
    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    @Override
    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return screen;
    }

    @Override
    public Handler getHandler(){
        return handler;
    }

    private void showInterstitial(){
        if(interstitial.isReady()){
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    private void prepareInterstitial(){
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

thank you for your kindness!

Comment: You can get idea about what is the actually reason for ANR by anr trace file.
DDMS -> File Explorer -> data -> anr -> traces.text

Comment: @maveň Thank you for your EDIT. I should have written this way. It's really readable!

Comment: @justDroid Thank you for your advice. And I **am** idiot. As soon as I read the `traces.txt`, I noticed that there is obviously doubtful code. In `onPause()` I call `stateChanged.wait()`. And it actually stuck. It works  when the game is running and `onDrawFrame()` is usually being called. But in this case, `onSurfaceCreate()` is called just after `onPause()` unexpectedly, so `wait()` never ends. I add `stateChanged.notifyAll()` to `onSurfaceCreate` and then ANR doesn`t appear again! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now, my remaining question is just one thing.  Why `resume()` is called when the screen turns off?